# Using material tailwind - tabs I am seeing weird behavior that does not match the example page

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

As mentioned in the title I am seeing weirdness when i use material tailwind. When switching between tabs I see like an artifact or something at the top of the page. Also, the styles do not match which makes me think i am missing some css in my implementation. See the video to see the issue.

Documentation: https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/tabs#tabs

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cQz5GTYjBvtUL6T5dOOKucqTgHs3O3Mb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide more details about the code and how you've set up the project.

Comment: @aarvinr Getting the code sample made me see my dumb mistake... thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a code sample I created a new react project (maybe not necessary but seemed like the best way). In the process of setting up that project I found my mistake. Basically I wasn't following the tailwind material steps correctly. I was missing some additional configuration in the tailwind.config file. Specifically wrapping the export in the `mt` function as documented in the below link.
https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/guide/cra

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = withMT({
 content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
 theme: {
   extend: {},
 },
 plugins: [],
})
```